# raw pixel array to gray scale BitmapImage

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have an array of raw pixel data. I would like to convert it into 8bpp Bitmap.

```
public static Bitmap ByteToGrayBitmap(byte[] rawBytes, int width, int height) 
{ 
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    BitmapData  bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
                                    ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);

    Marshal.Copy(rawBytes, 0, bitmapData .Scan0, rawBytes.Length);
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

    return bitmap;
}
```

bitmap looks like a color image instead of grayscale.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this before you return the bitmap:

```
for (int c = 0; c < bitmap.Palette.Entries.Length; c++)
    bitmap.Palette.Entries[c] = Color.FromArgb(c, c, c);
```

It will create a typical grayscale palette.

Comment: See TaW answer below.  Palette property cannot be modified in place.  Need to get Palette property, set Entries to grayscale, then set Palette property.

Comment: @ewd You are right, `Palette` property returns a copy instead of  reference. I will update the code at least. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You need a 8-bit grayscale palette in your image.

Add this before you return:

```
var pal = bmp.Palette;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) pal.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
bmp.Palette = pal;

return bmp;
```