# converting bitmap to 8bpp grayscale outputs as 8bpp coloured index in c#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap

I'm trying to convert bitmap to 8bpp grayscale with the code below

```
private Bitmap ConvertPixelformat(ref Bitmap Bmp)
{
       Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(Bmp);
        // Clone a portion of the Bitmap object.
        Rectangle cloneRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height);
        PixelFormat format = PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed;
        Bitmap cloneBitmap = myBitmap.Clone(cloneRect, format);
        var pal = cloneBitmap.Palette;

        for (i = 0; i < cloneBitmap.Palette.Entries.Length; ++i)
        {
            var entry = cloneBitmap.Palette.Entries[i];
            var gray = (int)(0.30 * entry.R + 0.59 * entry.G + 0.11 * entry.B);
            pal.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(gray, gray, gray);
        }
        cloneBitmap.Palette = pal;
        cloneBitmap.SetResolution(500.0F, 500.0F);
        return cloneBitmap;
}
```

Checking the properties of the bitmap image shows that the bit depth is correctly set to 8bpp but not as a grayscale rather it is a coloured index 8bpp.  Kindly guide on what to do.

Comment: Does it look right? Not sure about the way your palette is created. A normal  [grayscale Palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087075/raw-pixel-array-to-gray-scale-bitmapimage/29087197?s=3|36.7609#29087197) will have all values. If Clone shall have any chance to pick up on the palette, it would have to be there first. Maynbe you need DrawImage, but I'm not sure there..

Comment: @TaW Yes it does. It appears i need to  modify the code to output a grayscale 8bpp bitmap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Examine the following code:

```
    public static unsafe Bitmap ToGrayscale(Bitmap colorBitmap)
    {
        int Width = colorBitmap.Width;
        int Height = colorBitmap.Height;

        Bitmap grayscaleBitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

        grayscaleBitmap.SetResolution(colorBitmap.HorizontalResolution,
                             colorBitmap.VerticalResolution);

        ///////////////////////////////////////
        // Set grayscale palette
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        ColorPalette colorPalette = grayscaleBitmap.Palette;
        for (int i = 0; i < colorPalette.Entries.Length; i++)
        {
            colorPalette.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
        }
        grayscaleBitmap.Palette = colorPalette;
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        // Set grayscale palette
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        BitmapData bitmapData = grayscaleBitmap.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(Point.Empty, grayscaleBitmap.Size),
            ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

        Byte* pPixel = (Byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;

        for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
            {
                Color clr = colorBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);

                Byte byPixel = (byte)((30 * clr.R + 59 * clr.G + 11 * clr.B) / 100);

                pPixel[x] = byPixel;
            }

            pPixel += bitmapData.Stride;
        }

        grayscaleBitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

        return grayscaleBitmap;
    }
```

this code converts a color image to a grayscale image.

Comment: 8bpp can perfectly be non-grayscale... in fact, there's not actually any specific type in `System.Drawing` for "grayscale 8bpp". It all depends on the colour palette, which your code specifically sets to gray colours..

Comment: @Nyerguds, show me how to create an 8bpp color image of Lena.

Comment: The only tricky bit is getting a good palette, which is usually done with K-means clustering methods (something I've been wanting to look into for the longest time but haven't gotten around to yet. But there are plenty of methods out there for it). But once you got that, you just need to match the image's pixels to their nearest palette match using Cartesian distance. That's not hard at all.